# Trying to create partition index but creating replica index in Couchbase Why?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to create a partitioned index using the below query in Couchbase

```
CREATE INDEX adv_firstOpen ON data(state, name, zip, status) 
WHERE type = 'Event' and name = 'firstOpen'
WITH {"num_partition":4, 
"nodes":["node1:9001", "node2:9001", "node3:9001","node4:9001" ]}
```

but creating replication index

[image]

what is the issue in creating an index query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the Couchbase document got an idea to create a proper index

```
CREATE INDEX adv_firstOpen ON data(state, name, zip, status) 
PARTITION BY HASH(state) 
WHERE type = 'Event' and name = 'firstOpen' WITH {"num_partition":4}
```

here `num_partition` is enough in with condition and `PARTITION BY HASH` must be mention

[image]

Comment: Has PARTITION BY HASH(exprs) are must for partition index. otherwise it ignores num_partition.